# How to typecast a variable with the type stored in another variable?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = 4
b = float(a)
c = 'float'
```

Now, the doubt comes when the target type is stored in another variable.

```
b = c(a)
```

This would raise error.

Comment: Python has no type casting. You simply have a `float()` callable that you apply to another variable. You want dynamic variable lookups here.

Comment: You currently store the string `'float'` in c. You _can_ store `float` in it, but you need to get rid of the quotes: `c = float`. Then `b = c(a)` should work.

Comment: So how to do dynamic variable lookups?

Comment: @L3viathan
I have the datatype stored as a string in another variable and that is the limitation. How can I still typecast it?

Comment: See the duplicate. Built-in names such as `float` live in `builtins`, so `import builtins` then `getattr(builtins, c)` gives you the `float` object to call.

Comment: You can also pre-define your own dictionary: `types = {'float': float, 'str': str, ...}` then `types[c]` to get the callable.